# How to split an image into subimages?

Tags: image, dm-script

I would like to divide an image into a series of 256x256 pixels images.

The only coding method I thought of is drawing 256x256 ROI on the image and then create/crop a new image from the ROI area. (Please see the  code below.)

```
Number size_x, size_y
image img 
img := GetFrontImage()
getsize( img, size_x, size_y )
showimage( img )

number x, y
For( y=0; y+256<size_y; y+=256 )
{
    For ( x=0; x+256<size_x; x+=256 )
    {
         ROI EMROI = NewROI()
         EMROI.ROISetRectangle( x, y, 256, 256 )
         img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayAddROI( EMROI )
         image cropped=img[]
         showimage(cropped)
    }
}
```

But there are two bugs: The script only draws ROIs in X-direction, not in Y-direction, and it always creates the new image only from the first ROI. 
Is there a better way to divide DM images? Or how should I change my code to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is answering your question regarding the thing you want to achieve (the splitting of and image).

Yes, there is a better way to do this. You can address any "subsection" of a data directly by using the `[ t, l, b, r ]` notation in which you use the 4 numbers to specify the region. `t` top, `l` left, `b` bottom, `r`, right as in:

[image: Corodinates]

Or, alternativly, you can use the `slice` command to address subsections using a starting point, and then for each output dimension a triplet specifying *direction, length, stride* as in:

[image: Slice command]

---

### The script you want would likely be a variant of the following

```
// Create TestImage
number sx = 1024
number sy = 1024
image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, sx, sy )
img = itheta * sin( (iradius+icol)/iwidth * 50 * pi() )
img.ShowImage()

// Split up into N x M images
// Optional: Perform check for integer-values using mod-division (% operator)
number n = 2
number m = 4
number notExact = ( sx % n != 0 ) || ( sy % m != 0 ) 
if ( notExact ) 
    if ( !OKCancelDialog( "The image split is not an integer division. Continue?" ) ) 
        exit(0)

number bx = sx/n
number by = sy/m

for( number row = 0; row < m; row++ )
    for( number col= 0; col< n; col++ )
        {
            // We want the sub-rect. We could use [t,l,b,r] notation, but I prefer slice2()
            number x0 = col * bx
            number y0 = row * by
            image sub := img.Slice2( x0,y0,0, 0,bx,1, 1,by,1 ).ImageClone() // CLONE the referenced data to create a copy
            sub.SetName( img.GetName() + "__"+col+"_"+row )
            sub.ShowImage()
        }
```

---

If something remains unclear, please ask!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It looks like only works to the "real image" (the test image you created is real image). I remember there is command to get the real part of an image, but I can not find it by searching with the DM help file. What is the code? Thanks again!

Comment: Could we revise this script to make this function to work for an image that the customers provided (get front image, the image type may not be real image)? Thanks,

Comment: @together I think it should work with a getfrontimage right away. „Image“ variables are generally agnostic to the type as are the slice or clone commands. There are very few situations where a specific type is needed (FFTs are one, binary morphology another).

Comment: @together the commands for complex to real are ‘real’ and ‘imaginary’. You find them in the F1 help under the “references” section, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer regarding what is wrong with your script:

> You use the command `ROISetRectangle` incorrectly.

The parameters of the command are not X,Y,height,width but the same *top  / left / bottom / right* notation I have descriped in the other answer for the [t,l,b,r] notation.

Your script would actually work if you replace the one line by:

`EMROI.ROISetRectangle( y, x, y + 256, x + 256 )`

> There is no need to use "visual" ROIs for what you want. (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779567/1302888))

Instead of `[]` to use specify a visual ROI, you can use `[t,l,b,r]` to specify the region directly. Note, that you could also add the ROI you added by a simple command:

`img.SetSelection( t, l, b, r )`

with the same meaning of t,l,b,r.

The ImageDisplay and ROI command you use are the "lower level" commands whihc can do more things. You use them correclty, but you don't always need to use them, if you can get things done with simpler commands.

> It is usually a better syntax to define the variables used in a `for` loop within the for-loop and not outside of it. This will make them *local* and prevents unwanted potential bugs.

Instead of

```
number x
for( x=0; x<10; x++ )
{
}
```

Use

```
for( number x=0; x<10; x++ )
{
}
```

> Careful when copying images. the `=` operator will only copy the *values*. You can use the `:=` operator to *address* any data or sub-data (no addtional memory) and then use the command `ImageClone()` to create an exact copy, including meta-data such as calibrations or tags.

So in you script you may want to use

```
image cropped := ImageClone( img[] )
```